# Set router for different roles Meteor Js

Tags: javascript, meteor, router

How can I set router for different roles. This is my code. Can someone help me out.

```
if (Roles.userIsInRole(['admin'])) {
    Router.go('/addItem');
}
else {
    Roles.userIsInRole(['admin-category'])
    Router.go('/AddCategory');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use `iron:router`, you can achieve this several ways.
You can set a `onBeforeAction` hook on a route which will redirect to the appropriate route/template with `Router.go`, [check Hooks on the doc](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/). 
You should also be able to render a different template depending on your conditions:

```
if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), ['admin'])) {
    this.render('addItem');
} else if Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), ['admin-category']) {
    this.render('addCategory');
} else {
    this.render('defaultRoute');
}
```